# Javascript Escape Characters

Tags: javascript

I have kind of a lazy form that has two textboxes.  When I click a button I basically concatenate the two textboxes with a delimiter.  Is there like a special delimiter that cannot actually be typed in an html textbox, even if the &#xxx; syntax is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why concatenate? How about using JSON?

A simple and safe concatenation format would be

```
<length of the first string> <space> <first string> <second string>
```

For example

```
'abcd' + 'foo' => '4 abcdfoo'
```

Comment: Natural extension to an arbitrary number of strings: `4 abcd 3 foo 3 bar`. But I'd still go with JSON if I had to string-encode complex data (if you can call an array complex).

Comment: This is more or less what I want.  I have to look into JSON now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you want to disallow characters you'll have to add some sort of javascript to prevent them being entered.  Or just remove them from each field before joining.

Answer (score 0):

Anything can be typed into a textfield, which is why it is so important to sanitize all user input.